# c# Bouncy Castle Blowfish Decryption - Pad block corrupted

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt a blowfish encrypted string with Bouncycastle in C#.

I am able to easily encrypt and decrypt my own string but, unfortunately, I have to decrypt a string that is generated by another system.

I AM able to recreate that same string with C# / Bouncycastle using the following but I have yet to decrypt it successfully.

```
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
```

...

```
    static readonly Encoding Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    public string BlowfishEncrypt(string strValue, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();

            PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(engine);

            KeyParameter keyBytes = new KeyParameter(Encoding.GetBytes(key));

            cipher.Init(true, keyBytes);

            byte[] inB = Encoding.GetBytes(strValue);

            byte[] outB = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(inB.Length)];

            int len1 = cipher.ProcessBytes(inB, 0, inB.Length, outB, 0);

            cipher.DoFinal(outB, len1);

            return BitConverter.ToString(outB).Replace("-", "");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Below is what I have for decryption at the moment. The line that fails with error "pad block corrupted" is `cipher.DoFinal(out2, len2);`

```
    public string BlowfishDecrypt(string name, string keyString)
    {


        BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(engine);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        cipher.Init(false, new KeyParameter(Encoding.GetBytes(keyString)));

        byte[] out1 = Convert.FromBase64String(name);
        byte[] out2 = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(out1.Length)];

        int len2 = cipher.ProcessBytes(out1, 0, out1.Length, out2, 0);

        cipher.DoFinal(out2, len2); //Pad block corrupted error happens here

        String s2 = BitConverter.ToString(out2);

        for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++) {
            char c = s2[i];
            if (c != 0) {
                result.Append(c.ToString());
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();

    }
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong in BlowfishDecrypt()?

Note: 
I converted the above (encrypt and decrypt) from a bouncycastle Java example I found somewhere; the encrypt works. The only difference I can see is that the Java example uses a StringBuffer where I use a StringBuilder.

Comment: I guess `name` in `BlowfishDecrypt` is the encoded ciphertext from `BlowfishEncrypt`. If so, you have an encoding mismatch. You're encoding the ciphertext to Hex during encryption, but try to decode it from Base64 during decryption. Choose one encoding and stick to it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. An example of "name" would be the result of BlowfishEncrypt(). 

What you're saying makes sense but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve it. I changed `byte[] out1 = Convert.FromBase64String(name);` to `byte[] out1 = Encoding.GetBytes(name);` but get the same error.

Comment: It's been a long day... that should have obviously been `Hex.Decode(name)` .

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Blowfish really should not be used in new code, even the author now uses AES.

Comment: "unfortunately, I have to decrypt a string that is generated by another system"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Artjom B!

```
byte[] out1 = Convert.FromBase64String(name);
```

Should have been

```
byte[] out1 = Hex.Decode(name);
```

From there, all I had to do was convert the Hex to a string.